# Assets compile failed with out of memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I try to compile assets on the production server, but when I run rake task with compile - process goes too long and I get error with memory out.There is trace

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke bower:before_precompile (first_time)
** Execute bower:before_precompile
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
ExecJS::RuntimeError: FATAL ERROR: Evacuation Allocation failed - process out of memory
(execjs):1
/home/ubuntu/staging/releases/21/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:219:in `exec_runtime'
/home/ubuntu/staging/releases/21/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in `exec'
/home/ubuntu/staging/releases/21/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:21:in `eval'
/home/ubuntu/staging/releases/21/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:46:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/staging/releases/21/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.1/lib/uglifier.rb:212:in `run_uglifyjs'
/home/ubuntu/staging/releases/21/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.1/lib/uglifier.rb:179:in `compile'
/home/ubuntu/staging/releases/21/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:52:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/staging/releases/21/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/staging/releases/21/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/home/ubuntu/staging/releases/21/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
```

I also try run this with `config.assets.compile = false` but I get same error, how I can fix it?
sorry for my bad English

Comment: I had the same error exactly at a virtual machine with ruby 2 and rails 3.2. The only solution for me was to precompile at a machine with a bigger memory.

Comment: I solved this added a swap to server